# Silent installation of SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

We need to install SQL Server Express 2012 silently without any user interaction.

Could someone please refer me to any online documentation to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The microsoft documentation can be found here [Install SQL Server Express 2012 from Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). The main options for a silent install are /Q (silent install without user interface) and /QS (shows progress but without the possibility of any user interaction).